# is the below sentence correct? should be use "to" or "in" after the word exposure?

Tags: sentence-construction

he has gained exposure in various fields  like Management Consultancy. should be use "to" or "in" after the word exposure?

Comment: The sentence does prompt the question of which fields are **like** Management Consultancy. **Including** would work better.

Answer (score 1):

Depends what you mean.

> he has gained exposure in various fields like Management Consultancy

Within fields like management consultancy, he has achieved some degree of prominence or public visibility.

> he has gained exposure to various fields like Management Consultancy

He has encountered and gained experience in fields such as management consultancy.